# How to populate a star schema using Azure Datafactory v2

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a few source feeds from which I want to extract the data into a traditional star schema database (Azure SQL Database) for OLAP purposes, using Azure Data Factory v2.

Most of the source feeds corresponds to a dimension, so they map to the schema in my data warehouse database, apart from the internal surrogate key.

Then I have another feed which corresponds pretty much to the fact table. A lot of the identifiers there correspond to business keys of dimension tables.

The Azure Data Factory v2 documentation for the Copy Activity recommends that as much as possible, it uses the (default) *[Bulk Copy API to copy the data in append mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#considerations-for-the-sink)*.

So my questions are:

1. What is the best approach to sync my dimension tables. I do not want to delete my existent data and repopulate it, because it will ruin my surragate keys, which will be referred to by my fact table. I was thinking to use an *upsert* stored procedure, which checks if the row already exists, and does an update instead of an insert. Is this something that will be very slow? Is there a better approach for this (maybe using the preCopy Script in some way?).
2. When populating the fact table, I want to lookup all the respective IDs (surragate keys) of the dimensions, and convert all the business keys to those IDs prior to inserting the data. What is the recommended approach to achieve this? Again a stored procedure would probably do, but I am afraid it is slow. Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach I (and some of my friends) know is to MERGE the data.

To achieve that - create a staging table (the same or different database on the same target server) which has the same structure as source table + PK only.
Hence, the process in ADF should be split into 2 steps:

1. Truncate target (staging) table
2. Insert all data from the source into staging
3. Run stored procedure which contains MERGE statement and all required logic in there.

Having that approach you will keep:

- best performance while putting the data into a staging table (bulk)
- the fastest method to upsert (update/insert) your target table
- capability to implement sophisticated business logic
- apply SCD (Slowly Changing Dimension) when required
- reduce the amount of disk operation

The following posts could help you understand the process and build whole MERGE statement: [https://sqlplayer.net/category/bi/data-warehousing/ ]

It's a pretty common scenario, so you gave me an idea for a new blog post. Thx.

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. In the meantime I found this blog post, but its a bit old (ADF v1) so you have to understand a lot of the JSON stuff that nowadays is done through wizards: https://dataninjago.com/2017/11/08/end-to-end-azure-data-factory-pipeline-for-data-warehouse-elt-part-1/ . If you write one for ADFv2 it would be great :)

Comment: Btw, is there an installer or executable version of your SCD Merge Wizard tool I can download? I would love to try it, but it seems I would have to download the source and build it?

Comment: Cheers, will have a go at your recommended flow.

Comment: Apologize @jbx, for some reasons I missed all your comments.  
SCD Merge Wizard has its own MSI file: https://github.com/SQLPlayer/SCD-Merge-Wizard/releases/tag/v4.2.1

Comment: Thanks. I did manage to try it out back then (i think i had found the installer), but it had a few bugs and I ended up writing my own SCD queries. For some reason connecting to Azure SQL Database caused it to often fail to connect (retrying sometimes works), and I always had to re-enter the password for each query (even though I pressed save password), and sometimes it got confused when choosing which fields I wanted to be SCD1 and SCD3, and in the end gave up. Nice idea though.